# What is the minimum possible size for an asteroid to be able to alter Earth's orbit?

Tags: orbital-motion, collision, earth, celestial-mechanics, asteroids

Obviously, the question as posed in the title is very incomplete. Allow me to rephrase it in more specific terms:

> What are the minimum possible "combined parameters" (velocity, mass, angle of impact,?) for an asteroid be able to "significantly" (I agree that this is ambiguous too) alter Earth's orbit after impact?

Comment: Hi Matemáticos, no offense intended, but  it's not **that** difficult to work out, it's  basically two rocks hitting each other.   take say one of the 1,000 NEO asteroids such as  this one that NASA is going to: http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-37309903      500m wide

Comment: this [page](http://impact.ese.ic.ac.uk/ImpactEffects/) contains all the answers you need ( there is a link to a document ). Bonus : you can test any crazy scenario

Answer (score 2):

Any asteroid no matter the size that comes close to the Earth will change the orbit by gravitational forces a little. The change may be so minuet its not measurable by instruments but is measurable by math.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Earth-crossing_minor_planets
[image]